# Is it true that a USPTO patent not safe from European companies?

Tags: patent-infringement, international, uspto, pct, freedom-to-operate

All feedback is greatly appreciated. I'm a very young inventor.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not filing in other places, then your patent is not protected in those countries, which means that they will be able to produce products there and sell them in all other places where your patent was not filed.

If you file in the US only, you will be protected in the US, European companies will not be allowed to sell here. You will be able to sell everywhere - meaning competing without protection.